# Can I cycle or run with shoulder niggles?

Tags: running, swimming, bicycling

I have developed a slight niggle in my right shoulder. Reason could be because of over workout in swimming.
The niggle is light pain when I move my shoulders a bit fast with some weight on it. For example pulling the water while swimming. It is not severe and all. That is why mentioned it as niggles.

Now my question is, can I cycle or run?
I have planned for a slow jogging or very slow cycling(both being a bit long) for coming three days followed with one day's rest and then start swimming.

Is it okay? Any suggestions?

The answer I am expecting is similar to this:
For different extent of shoulder injury, different allowance of running or cycling can be done or may be that there is no such thing (can do running or cycling, it doesn't matter to the shoulder at all) or may be that I shouldn't do both.

Comment: Answering your question would require us to diagnose your injury, which we probably won't be able to do.

Comment: If it is not severe at all, what makes you think it will affect your cycling or running?

Comment: You may find this information of interest about [Shoulder overuse injury and swimming](http://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/7225/rotator-cuff-strengthening-for-shoulder-overuse-injury)

Comment: Medical advice is off topic here, please read the [faq].

Comment: Agreed, it is off topic. And, based on your series of questions recent, I would recommend you find a coach you can discuss items with about training.

Comment: You most likely have trigger point in your supraspinatus on the side with the messed up shoulder. I've fixed several biker's shoulder issues by massaging those trigger points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I found this a bit subjective, hence I am answering it myself.
The shoulder niggle may vary for different person.
When we call it 'niggle' which means slight but persistent discomfort is not a serious injury but one has to be careful with it, since it may lead to some serious injury.

I took rest for a day and then the next 2 days I followed the exercises given in [this link](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/7225/rotator-cuff-strengthening-for-shoulder-overuse-injury) without weights.
It was very helpful.

And then the following day I cycled 50 km and the following day I ran a half marathon and I made my personal best. This is very subjective, I know.

But in my opinion, after experiencing the constantly irritating niggle in my shoulder, cycling or running doesn't hurt the shoulder, provided resting 1 or 2 days.